# Gathman's definition of projective $n$-space over a field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

I am currently reading **Plane Alegbraic Curves** by *Andreas Gathmann*. This book defines the projective $n$-space (which is denoted by $\mathbb{P}^n$) over a field $K$ as the set of all $1$-dimensional vector spaces of $K^{n+1}$ (where $K^{n+1}$ is regraded as a vector space over $K$). The book then characterizes $\mathbb{P}^n$ as follows: Define a relation $\rho$ on $K^{n+1}\setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ as follows 
\begin{align}
(x_0,\ldots,x_n) \rho (y_0,\ldots,y_n) 
\iff \exists \lambda \in K^* : (x_0,\ldots,x_n) = \lambda (y_0,\ldots,y_n).
\end{align}
Then the books says that $\mathbb{P}^n = (K^{n+1}  \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace )/ \rho$. I wonder how this is possible?. Clearly, every equivalence class $[(x_0,\ldots,x_n)]_{\rho}$ fails even to be a vector subspace over $K$ since $0\not\in [(x_0,\ldots,x_n)]_{\rho}$ (The zero of $K^{n+1}$). Am I right?. If I`m mistaken, can anyone please help me understanding my mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The characterization is not an actual set-theoretic equality. But there is a bijection between them. The equivalence class $[(x_0,\cdots,x_n)]_\rho$ corresponds to the subspace generated by $(x_0,\cdots,x_n)$.

Comment: (Commenting because I am not an expert, just some grad student) - take any element in $\mathbb{P}^n$, then this *element* represents a vector space in $K^{n+1}$. Then, such an element represents a vector space in one dimension (basically, the span of one vector). For each such element, we simply also include the $0$ and indeed, we can add a vector to itself and do scalar multiplication, and still be represented by the same element.

Comment: I was confused with the equality sign. Now, I got the idea. @awllower

Comment: The only thing missing to make each equivalence class into a subspace is the zero vector, so it's basically fine.